# Recognizing a Tap on the Title in UINavigation Bar

Tags: ios, objective-c

Could someone please help me recognize a tap when a user taps on the Title in the Navigation Bar, in Objective-C?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following :

1) add button as your title view of navigation

```
UIButton *titleLabelButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[titleLabelButton setTitle:@"myTitle" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
titleLabelButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 70, 44);
titleLabelButton.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
[titleLabelButton addTarget:self action:@selector(didTapTitleView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
self.navigationItem.titleView = titleLabelButton;
```

2)Implement the Selector

```
- (IBAction)didTapTitleView:(id) sender{
    //Perform your actions
    NSLog(@"Title tap");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you can't directly have a touch event on the `title` property of `UINavigationItem` of `UINavigationBar`.

There is a property `titleView`, which you can set and have a touch event on it. So you could make an `UILabel` and set it to the `UINavigationItem`.

```
[self.navigationItem setTitleView:label];
```

You can then set a tap event on this `label`.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didTapTitle:)];
[label addGestureRecognizer:tap];

- (void)didTapTitle:(UILabel *)label {
    //handle tap...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UITapGestureRecognizer * tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                            initWithTarget:self
                                            action:@selector(hideKeyBoard)];

    tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
    [self.navigationController.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];


-(void)hideKeyBoard
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to use a custom title view and add a tap gesture recognizer to it.

Try this in `viewDidLoad`:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer* tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(navTitleTapped)];

UILabel* navigationTitleLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 50)];
navigationTitleLabel.text = @"The title goes here...";
[navigationTitleLabel addGestureRecognizer:tap];

self.navigationItem.titleView = navigationTitleLabel;
```

Then, implement `navTitleTapped`

```
-(void)navTitleTapped
{
    //do what you need to do
}
```